# Get execution time of queries from hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

Hibernate provides the API of `getQueries()` (through `org.hibernate.stat.Statistics`), which gives an array of query strings.  Can we further get the execution time of these queries?.

If this facility is not directly available, are there some indirect ways (e.g. by writing some small program) to get the needed information?  I now have a list of ~15 query strings, and I want some hints as to how to direct my effort for  optimization of performance.

I have read the relevant documentation but this is not obvious to me.

P.S. I am using Hibernate 4.2

**References:**

1. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html#getQueries()
2. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-monitoring
3. http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-activate-hibernate-statistics-to-analyze-performance-issues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but how about `getQueryStatistics`? The returned `QueryStatistics` includes min, max and average time as well as execution count. You should be able to pass the query strings from `getQueries` to the method in order to get the details.